# Is there a non set theoretic definition of a function?

Tags: functions

I know we can call function different names like mapping, transformation but can we describe what a function is without using set theory ?

Comment: You can describe it in lay terms, certainly... "*a method or process of taking some input and giving an output such that performing the method on the same input will give consistent results.*"  That said, for a fully rigorous definition, the set theory definition is by far the most common.

Comment: Yes, there is one within e.g. type theory or lambda calculus.

Comment: A function is a box that, when you put a mathematical object into it, a mathematical object comes out; moreover, the object that comes out depends only on the object you put in.

Comment: It is possible to use "function" as a primitive concept, instead of "set", and to axiomatize mathematics on that basis. In fact, the original formulation, due to von Neumann, of what is now called "Neumann-Bernays-Gödel (NBG) set theory", was of this form.

Comment: @Randy sorry for being late, how do they define it in type theory ?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the info. I really want to see how mathematics looks without set theory as a foundation. Will check that out.

Comment: Gerry described it well. Types are "boxes" and a function is a certain kind of a box (a "function type").

Comment: Ha. I'm a type theorist, and I didn't even know it!